# Website testing / browser automation tools

Tags: web-browser, automation, software-testing, user-interface, unit-tests

I'm looking for a tool, that will automatically performs specified actions such as clicking on links, filling and submitting forms, and so on. I mean I write some kind of script with instructions and the program will execute it. I want to use it for testing websites and want to repeat the same test sequence many times, so I don't want to do it manually.

> Important requirement is that it must allow me to **use**
>   **conditions** and **store values** during the test run.

For example: If there is a login button (which means we are not logged in) then perform login sequence first, but if there is a logout button (we are logged in), then go to products page and click on the first product. It should also allows me to read and store the name of the first product into a variable that will be used later.

I was trying multiple solutions:

- Selenium and Selenium IDE - First is overly complicated even to install it, not to mention using it. I'm not even sure if there is any possibility to use variables or conditions - if so, it is not so easy. Second is very impractical macro recording tool with bugged UI.
- Alternatives like Codeception, iMacros, DalekJS and others - they are all just a macrorecording or scripting tools that does not allow to use conditions, only strictly given sequence of commands.

Are there any paid or free solutions for this, without overly complicated installations and settings? It should preferably use a browser (Chrome, FF) to display what the test is doing or what the currently tested loaded page looks like, not only the results or log.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and fastest possible way to automate browser **AND** use conditions like "*if we're logged in do this, otherwise do this*" is this free chrome extension:

http://automatron.activit.sk

It has no macro recording options or graphical click/select IDE, but writing scripts is really fun. There are many browser automation products that claims to be simple, but has no conditions & variables support or it is not that simple at all.

If you don't mind the necessity of writing scripts and a single-browser support this is a tool for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/) is exactly what you are looking for. It is an automated testing tool for desktop, web and mobile applications and it lets you use both capture & replay and coding, so you can perfectly add conditions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Testsigma is one of the codeless Automation Tools that you can use to meet the requirement and I'm one of the core team members.

So, coming to the sample requirement,

> If there is a login button (which means we are not logged in) then perform login
>   sequence first, but if there is a logout button (we are logged in), then go to 
>   products page and click on the first product. It should also allow me to read
>   and store the name of the first product into a variable that will be used later.

We can create the above scenario easily using the built-in If-then conditional structure in Testsigma. Also, for the ones who are getting started to these kind of stuff, we also provide a Recorder Utility with which you can record first and then add the conditions as required.

Also, we have different test data variables which can be used to drive the tests using provided data(data driven tests) and these variables can also be used to store the values that need to be used on later in the steps.

When executing the tests locally, you can watch in real time. If you are using the Cloud devices, you can watch the recorder test execution video and also inspect the step-by-step screenshots.